# How to update billing state when I select country with Chosen.js

Tags: magento-1.7

I have chosen.js used in magento. Problem is that when I select country, like Germany, state is not updated with german states. Anyone know how to fire that change.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3qE6.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure and not the magento JS pro, but if I'm correct this happens with

```
shippingRegionUpdater.update();
```

And the `shippingRegionUpdater` is defined here:

```
//app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml:154
var shippingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater(
    'shipping:country_id',
    'shipping:region',
    'shipping:region_id',
    <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>,
    undefined,
    'shipping:postcode'
);
```

`RegionUpdater` is defined here: `/js/varien/form.js:163`